# How to avoid N+1 queries for has_many :through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, graphql-ruby

I'm building a GraphQL API with Ruby on Rails and the graphql gem. Now I have some `n:m` relations, like `Projects` have many `Users` and `Users` have many `Projects`. My models are like:

```rb
# /app/models/project.rb

has_many :project_assignments
has_many :project_managers, through: :project_assignments, source: :user
```

```rb
# /app/models/project_assignment.rb

belongs_to :project
belongs_to :user
```

```rb
# /app/models/user.rb

has_many :project_assignments
has_many :projects, through: :project_assignments
```

Now I want to query all projects and their corresponding project managers with a query like this:

```
query {
  projects {
    edges {
      node {
        id        
        projectManagers {
          edges {
            node {
              id
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my resolvers are basically like `Project.all` and each `Project` calls `project.projectManagers`, which results in hundreds of queries:

```
  Project Load (3.3ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects"
  User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "project_assignments" ON "users"."id" = "project_assignments"."user_id" WHERE "project_assignments"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 2]]
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "project_assignments" ON "users"."id" = "project_assignments"."user_id" WHERE "project_assignments"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 3]]
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "project_assignments" ON "users"."id" = "project_assignments"."user_id" WHERE "project_assignments"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 4]]
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "project_assignments" ON "users"."id" = "project_assignments"."user_id" WHERE "project_assignments"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 5]]
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "project_assignments" ON "users"."id" = "project_assignments"."user_id" WHERE "project_assignments"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 6]]
...
```

I've added the bullet gem, but there is no warning about a missing eager loading. In fact, If I use `Project.all.includes(:project_managers)`, I get the query that I want (`SELECT "project_assignments".* FROM "project_assignments" WHERE "project_assignments"."project_id" IN ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, ...)`), but the `User` queries fires anyhow:

```
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN ($1, $2, $3)  [["id", 3], ["id", 2], ["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "project_assignments" ON "users"."id" = "project_assignments"."user_id" WHERE "project_assignments"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 2]]
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "project_assignments" ON "users"."id" = "project_assignments"."user_id" WHERE "project_assignments"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 3]]
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "project_assignments" ON "users"."id" = "project_assignments"."user_id" WHERE "project_assignments"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 4]]
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "project_assignments" ON "users"."id" = "project_assignments"."user_id" WHERE "project_assignments"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 5]]
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "project_assignments" ON "users"."id" = "project_assignments"."user_id" WHERE "project_assignments"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 6]]
...
```

Is there anything that I can do the preload the users?

I tried `eager_load` also, but the result is basically the same (tried another example with an normal `has_many` association (no `:through`):

```
  SQL (1.3ms)  SELECT "projects"."id" AS t0_r0, "projects"."title" AS t0_r1, "projects"."number" AS t0_r2, "projects"."description" AS t0_r3, "projects"."deadline" AS t0_r4, "projects"."archived" AS t0_r5, "projects"."customer_id" AS t0_r6, "projects"."rate_type" AS t0_r7, "projects"."daily_rate" AS t0_r8, "projects"."service_rates" AS t0_r9, "projects"."budget_type" AS t0_r10, "projects"."budget_rate" AS t0_r11, "projects"."created_at" AS t0_r12, "projects"."updated_at" AS t0_r13, "projects"."status" AS t0_r14, "projects"."slug" AS t0_r15, "project_labels"."id" AS t1_r0, "project_labels"."title" AS t1_r1, "project_labels"."description" AS t1_r2, "project_labels"."color" AS t1_r3, "project_labels"."project_id" AS t1_r4, "project_labels"."created_at" AS t1_r5, "project_labels"."updated_at" AS t1_r6 FROM "projects" LEFT OUTER JOIN "project_labels" ON "project_labels"."project_id" = "projects"."id" WHERE "projects"."id" IN ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10)  [["id", 1], ["id", 2], ["id", 3], ["id", 4], ["id", 5], ["id", 6], ["id", 7], ["id", 8], ["id", 9], ["id", 10]]
  ProjectLabel Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "project_labels".* FROM "project_labels" WHERE "project_labels"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 10]]
  ProjectLabel Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "project_labels".* FROM "project_labels" WHERE "project_labels"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 2]]
  ProjectLabel Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "project_labels".* FROM "project_labels" WHERE "project_labels"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 5]]
  ProjectLabel Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "project_labels".* FROM "project_labels" WHERE "project_labels"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 8]]
  ProjectLabel Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "project_labels".* FROM "project_labels" WHERE "project_labels"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 6]]
  ProjectLabel Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "project_labels".* FROM "project_labels" WHERE "project_labels"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 4]]
  ProjectLabel Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "project_labels".* FROM "project_labels" WHERE "project_labels"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 1]]
  ProjectLabel Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "project_labels".* FROM "project_labels" WHERE "project_labels"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 3]]
  ProjectLabel Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "project_labels".* FROM "project_labels" WHERE "project_labels"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 9]]
  ProjectLabel Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "project_labels".* FROM "project_labels" WHERE "project_labels"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 7]]
```

Comment: What's the definition for `.assignees` when you said `project.assignees`?

Comment: Oh, that was a typo, it's basically the same like calling `project.projectManagers`, because it's just another `has_many :through` association.

Comment: Okie, I'll write up something now, if it would help.

Answer (score 3):

You can do all sorts of things with [`has_many`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) including `includes` which should help with N+1 queries

```
has_many :project_assignments, -> { includes(:projects) }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Project.all.includes(:project_managers)
# Project.includes(:project_managers) # shorthand of above
```

... would include `project_managers` automatically in the SQL depending on the query.

To also include `project_assignment.user`, then just merge them:

```
Project.includes(:project_managers, project_assignments: :user)

# probably below is equivalent of above (but not sure)
# just because `project_managers` association is also going "through" :project_assignments
Project.includes(project_assignments: :user)
```

See ["Loading nested relationships" here in the docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes)